# parse a large file using perl json module

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have written a function that executes a command. The command produces a very large json output. I want the function to  parse a part of the output and return it to the calling function.

I want the function to return "lost_packets" , "packets" and "lost_percent" from `{end} {streams}{udp}` in the output.(indicated the values to be returned with arrows) i used decode_json. when I run the code ,I get the following error. "Bad name after...". I'm pretty sure the command gets executed and produces a json result. I believe i'm not parsing the json output correctly. Can someone help me out with the json parsing?

```
        use strict;
        use warnings;
        use JSON qw( decode_json );

    sub parse_json_output {

         my ($self) = @_;

        $self->{command}->execute( 'command goes here' );

        my @stdout = $self->{command}->stdOut();

        my $decoded = decode_json(@stdout); 
        my @output = @{$decoded->{'end'}{'streams'}{'udp'} } ; 
        foreach my $out (@output) {

         return  $out->{"packets"} . "\n";

    }

  }
```

function call :

$self->{'execute'}  =  $self->{'json_obj'}->parse_json_output();

command output :

```
{
    "start":    {
        "connected":    [{
                "socket":   4,
                "local_host":   "9.1.1.2",
                "local_port":   47669,
                "remote_host":  "8.2.0.2",
                "remote_port":  12009
            }],
        "version":  "iperf 3.0.11",
        "system_info":  "Linux nevada-client154 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux\n",
        "timestamp":    {
            "time": "Mon, 11 Apr 2016 22:57:30 GMT",
            "timesecs": 1460415450
        },
        "connecting_to":    {
            "host": "8.2.0.2",
            "port": 77545
        },
        "cookie":   "nevada-client154.1460415448.675315.5",
        "test_start":   {
            "protocol": "UDP",
            "num_streams":  1,
            "blksize":  576,
            "omit": 0,
            "duration": 0,
            "bytes":    0,
            "blocks":   4500,
            "reverse":  0
        }
    },
    "intervals":    [{
            "streams":  [{
                    "socket":   4,
                    "start":    0,
                    "end":  4.20106,
                    "seconds":  4.20106,
                    "bytes":    2592000,
                    "bits_per_second":  4.9359e+06,
                    "packets":  4500,
                    "omitted":  false
                }],
            "sum":  {
                "start":    0,
                "end":  4.20106,
                "seconds":  4.20106,
                "bytes":    2592000,
                "bits_per_second":  4.9359e+06,
                "packets":  4500,
                "omitted":  false
            }
        }],
    "end":  {
        "streams":  [{
                "udp":  {
                    "socket":   4,
                    "start":    0,
                    "end":  4.20106,
                    "seconds":  4.20106,
                    "bytes":    2592000,
                    "bits_per_second":  4.9359e+06,
                    "jitter_ms":    0.401183,
                    "lost_packets": 0,  ---------> i want this to be returned
                    "packets":  4499,   --------->  return 
                    "lost_percent": 0   --------- >  return
                }
            }],
        "sum":  {
            "start":    0,
            "end":  4.20106,
            "seconds":  4.20106,
            "bytes":    2592000,
            "bits_per_second":  4.9359e+06,
            "jitter_ms":    0.401183,
            "lost_packets": 0,
            "packets":  4499,
            "lost_percent": 0
        },
        "cpu_utilization_percent":  {
            "host_total":   1.09968,
            "host_user":    0.170654,
            "host_system":  0.928823,
            "remote_total": 0.00281493,
            "remote_user":  0.000502673,
            "remote_system":    0.00224273
        }
    },
    "server_output_text":   "-----------------------------------------------------------\nAccepted connection from 9.1.1.2, port 33836\n[  5] local 8.2.0.2 port 12009 connected to 9.1.1.2 port 47669\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is malformed. I ran it through a validator (there are many free online ones), and it came up with multiple errors. The validator i used said:

```
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 222]
Error:Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 222]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 226]
Error:Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 226]
Error:Expecting comma or }, not string.[Code 13, Structure 229]
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.[Code 17, Structure 229]
```

It looks like you have some missing double quotes somewhere along the line. If you're not using a library to generate the JSON for your data (which you should), then you should validate that your JSON is valid as often as possible - it's surprisingly easy to forget to escape a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

```
"streams":  [{ ... }],
```

means that `$data->{end}{streams}` holds an array reference that holds a hash reference. So the way to get to the `udp` element inside is

```
$decoded->{end}{streams}[0]{udp}
```

and the specific elements you want to return are at

```
print $decoded->{end}{streams}[0]{udp}{lost_packets};
print $decoded->{end}{streams}[0]{udp}{packets};
print $decoded->{end}{streams}[0]{udp}{lost_percent};
```

Comment: I tired the following. It doesn't seem to work. my $decoded = decode_json($json);

my @output = $decoded->{end}{stream}[0]{udp} ;
 foreach my $out (@output) {

   print $out->{end}{stream}[0]{udp}{lost_packets};

}

Comment: I get the following error : Use of uninitialized value in print

Comment: We misspelled `streams`.

Comment: i corrected it. I see the following. Can't use string ("4.20075") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in